# Open new window using salesforce custom button, links & actions

Tags: force.com

I need to open this page in a new window (salesforce tab.) Have tried to modify the URL but can't seem to get the syntax.

```
Button or Link URL  /apex/PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_PolicySample?AccId={!Audit__c.Id}
```

Comment: Did you set the Behavior attribute to New Window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

- Content Source: URL
- Behavior: Display in New Window
- URL:  `{!URLFOR("../apex/PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_PolicySample", "")}?AccId={!Audit__c.Id}`

Not sure if it's the most elegant way but this format works for us

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had the Display Type set to List Button which hid the 'New Window 'option.  Had copied mine from a related list .

Answer (score 3):

got it working with the execute javascript option and tweaking the syntax

```
var newWin = window.open("/apex/PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_PolicySample?AccId={!Audit__c.Id}", "_blank");
```